# Why is my MC Launcher crashing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I just installed Minecraft Demo on my Windows 10.

So, after all that download:

[image]

Whenever I click the button that says "play demo" the window closes and reopens with the same error message. What's going on?

*Merci d'avance!*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your computer? If so, then try downloading an anti-malware/spyware system such as Malwarebytes or Super Anti-Spyware and using it a couple times. I did this with my computer(which is 10 years old) and it worked. I'm not exactly how it worked, so I can't develop many hypotheses on ho to fix it, but that did the trick.